# Oracle string encoding issue

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8

I have a table with column named "Name" in SQL oracle.

Now Select name from table gives me  `DIAZ` while dump(name,16) gives

```
Typ=1 Len=5: a0,44,49,41,5a
```

I wanted to know which encoding the string is in?

Also, `convert(NAME_ELEM4,'UTF8')`  gives me `Â DIAZ`

Can someone explain me this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

may be it was just written into database with leading symbol a0 by client application?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: No, it is not. But it is not criticism neither. It is just an assumption which could be an answer.